# When I start MySQL it shuts down instantly

Tags: mysql, xampp, port

**My problem**

When I try to start MySQL it automaticly shuts down. It always worked fine until I downloaded sql server 2008r2. I don't know if it has something to do with it because when I run. `C:\> netstat -a -b` and `ctrl` + `f` the port I am using for MySQL it is not listed.

When I change the MySQL port to something else (a random number) nothing happends I am still getting the same errros.

If someone is fammiliar with this headache problem I would really appreciate the help.

Thank you in advance.

**Xampp error**

> 09:15:00  [mysql]     Attempting to start MySQL app...
>   09:15:01  [mysql]     Status change detected: running
>
> 09:15:02  [mysql]     Status change detected: stopped
>
> 09:15:02  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
>
> 09:15:02  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing
>   dependencies,
>
> 09:15:02  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by
>   another method.
>
> 09:15:02  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>
> 09:15:02  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>
> 09:15:02  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
>
> 09:15:02  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums

**Mysql_error.log**

> InnoDB: using atomic writes.
>
> 2020-05-27  9:15:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows
>   interlocked functions
>
> 2020-05-27  9:15:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
>
> 2020-05-27  9:15:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
>
> 2020-05-27  9:15:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
>
> 2020-05-27  9:15:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
>
> 2020-05-27  9:15:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total
>   size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
>
> 2020-05-27  9:15:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of
>   buffer pool
>
> 2020-05-27  9:15:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments
>   are active.
>
> 2020-05-27  9:15:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for
>   temporary tables
>
> 2020-05-27  9:15:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file
>   'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the
>   file full; Please wait ...
>
> 2020-05-27  9:15:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1'
>   size is now 12 MB.
>
> 2020-05-27  9:15:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>
> 2020-05-27  9:15:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence
>   number 47064; transaction id 9
>
> 2020-05-27  9:15:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from
>   C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
>
> 2020-05-27  9:15:00 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
>
> 2020-05-27  9:15:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at
>   200527  9:15:00
>
> 2020-05-27  9:15:00 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some
>   plugins may be not loaded
>
> 2020-05-27  9:15:00 0 [ERROR] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: unknown
>   variable 'innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=2M'
>
> 2020-05-27  9:15:00 0 [ERROR] Aborting

Comment: `c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: unknown variable 'innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=2M'` comment this out or remove it from my.ini

Comment: @LarsStegelitz I comment it out but the mysql is till shutting down the error i am getting now is " Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist"

Comment: Seems, then you have an corrupted installation...

Comment: @LarsStegelitz I think thats the issue ass well. I will reinstall :(. Thanks for the help